# dojox DataGrid onStyleRow works first time, then not again

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to make a legend using a DataGrid .  My problem is, I want the text in the Datagrid to be colored.  I use the onStyleRow function as outlined here: (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html) and it works the first time after deploying.  The text in the DataGrid comes up red, but if i refresh or open try it on a different browser, the DataGrid text does not come up red, just the standard black.

I was wondering, what I was doing wrong, Thanks, 
Here is my code:

```
if(dijit.byId("plotlegend")){
    dijit.byId("plotlegend").destroy();
}

var threadGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    id: 'plotlegend',
    store: oStore,
    structure: layout,
    rowsPerPage: 5,
    rowSelector: false,
    autoWidth: true,
    query: {},
    plotsObject: this.plotsObject,
    onStyleRow: function(row){
        var legend = this;
        var item = legend.getItem(row.index);
        if (item){
                var variableName = legend.store.getValue(item, "plot");
            if (variableName){
                var color = "color:red;";
                row.customStyles += color;
            }
        }

        legend.focus.styleRow(row);
        legend.edit.styleRow(row);
    }
},document.createElement('div'));

dojo.byId("plotlegendbc").appendChild(threadGrid.domNode);
threadGrid.startup();
threadGrid.update();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will solve your issue, but it's better if the last line of your custom style function is:
    dojox.grid.DataGrid.prototype.onStyleRow.apply(this, arguments);

(Remove the grid.focus.styleRow and grid.focus.edit.styleRow lines)
This code will be more forward compatible since it runs the default onStyleRow function directly.

Comment: Great! All the official docs don't mention this and show the (not working) code as seen in the question. This helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had more success in using **dojo.connect** to handle this event and properly apply styles.  I haven't used the individual styles as CSS classes are a better way to manage styles.  It is better for maintenance because then you don't have individual styles embedded in your JavaScript.  Here's a snippet of what works for me.  Keep in mind this is on Dojo 1.5.

```
var grid = dijit.byId('myDataGrid');
dojo.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow' , this, function(row) {                    
    var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
    if (item) {
        if(item.status != "viewed"){
            row.customClasses += " unRead";
        }else{
            row.customClasses += " read";
        }

        if(item.status == "not active"){
            row.customClasses += " dismissed";
        }
    }
    grid.focus.styleRow(row);
    grid.edit.styleRow(row);
});
```